# How to disable/enable click & key events in Typescript / Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling, dom-events

I got this method (written by a developer who quit) that is located in a service to disable keyboard-events. This is working well.
But there is missing an opposite method to enable the key events again. And I also try to write a similar method to disable/enable click events. The events must be disabled while a loading spinner is displayed and then be enabled again.

```
export interface KeyboardShortcutOptions {
  element: any;
  keys: string;
}
```

```
  constructor(
    private _eventManager: EventManager,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
  ) {}

  private _defaults: Partial<KeyboardShortcutOptions> = {
    element: this._document
  };

  disableKeyevents(): Observable<unknown> {
    const merged = { ...this._defaults };
    const event = `keydown`;

    return new Observable(observer => {
      const handler = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
        const key = e.key;

        if (key === 'Control' || key === 'F12') {
          observer.next(e);
          return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
      };

      const dispose = this._eventManager.addEventListener(
        merged.element,
        event,
        handler
      );

      return (): Function => dispose();
    });
  }
```

I tried to write the enableKeyevents-method like this. But it's not working.

```
  enableKeyevents(): Observable<unknown> {
    const merged = { ...this._defaults };
    const event = `keydown`;

    return new Observable(observer => {

      const handler = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
        observer.next(e);
        return;
      };

      const dispose = this._eventManager.addEventListener(
        merged.element,
        event,
        handler
      );

      return (): Function => dispose();
    });
  }
```

My disableClickEvents-method looks like this. Also not working.

```
  disableClickEvents(): Observable<unknown> {
    const merged = { ...this._defaults };
    const event = `click`;

    return new Observable(() => {
      
      const handler = (e: Event): void => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      const dispose = this._eventManager.addEventListener(
        merged.element,
        event,
        handler
      );

      return (): Function => dispose();
    });
  }
```

Any hint on what I am missing?

Comment: Can you not create a class with `pointer-events: none`, add it when the spinner is displayed, and remove it when the spinner is removed?

Comment: This does indeed sound a lot like "You should use `pointer-events: none` instead".

Comment: Thanks!
This css-solution was indeed much easier and is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a service, I would put a public boolean property in the service like this:

```
keyboardDisabled:boolean = false;
```

which is settable directly by calling the reference to the service `myKeyBoardService.keyboardDisabled` or settable through a public method

Then use this boolean in the `handler` function your colleague created, like this:

```
const handler = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
    const key = e.key;
    
    if(keyboardDisabled){
       if (key === 'Control' || key === 'F12') {
         observer.next(e);
         return;
       }

       e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

That way, you can control the effect of such handler (disable those effects or not). But this also means you have to get this addEventListener at the start of whatever component is using this service.

Which means you have to also transform the current `disableKeyevents` method into some sort of initialization method which is called in the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

This would also be easy to implement the same thing for mouse event handling.